# What do you call a person who doesn't believe in something but still saying things about it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a person who doesn't believe in something but still saying things about it?

For example let's say ***Mario*** doesn't believe in God (he is an atheist) and something bad happens to ***Mario*** so he says:

> Why me God?
>
> What did I do wrong to deserve this God?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theology or psychology, not the English language.

Comment: I would call that person normal. Just as there "are no atheists in a fox hole", it can be said that there are no atheists when someone is looking for a cosmic force to blame. Blaming the Fates is outdated. *O, Fortuna* isn't very satisfying. Personifying "the cosmos" is pretty normal in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest word to describe Mario would be a **hypocrite**, defined as one whose actions belie their professed beliefs.  Note that *hypocrite* is a fairly derogatory term in modern parlance - but then, it's hard to describe the behavior you're talking about in positive terms.  Still, if you were looking for a more "oh, well, there he goes again!" type of noun (i.e. "being silly" rather than "betraying his beliefs"), *hypocrite* is probably too strong/negative a term.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypocrite

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a noun referring to that person, but I have a verb and an adverb.

Mario is 'speaking figuratively'. You would have to explain elsewhere that he is an atheist.

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrase "**habitual vocabulary**" applies here.  Mario is not *necessarily* using the term "God" to refer to some supernatural creator who he believes in, though I think your examples could be taken either way.  He is potentially using the term out of habit, in the same way that other habitual vocabulary creeps in to our verbal communication.